# What does the double forward slash mean in haml code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

In this haml code

```
%select{class: 'dday-select', 'data-date' => ddate}
  //- if client.sunday? && current_admin_user.nil?
```

What does the line with // mean?

Answer (score 1):

This in an [HTML comment](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html_comments_), second slash most likely is ignored